# angular scope duplicate in dynamic directive

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome-extension, angularjs-scope

I'm building Chrome extension that inject script and Html tags to page.
And I use directive to dynamically load template and controller
as below

```
<content-page  content-url="{{IndexCtrl.partialPage}}">
</content-page>
```

in contactPage directive:

```
myApp.directive('contentPage',function($compile){

  return {
    restrict: "E",
    replace:true,

    link: function(scope, el, attrs){

        attrs.$observe('contentUrl',function(pageUrl){

            $.ajax({
                url : pageUrl,
                success : function(result){

                    el.html(result).show();

                    $compile(el.contents())(scope);

                }
            });


        })
    }
  }
})
```

and I assign controller in html file, for example 'pageUrl' point to this html file:

```
<div ng-controller="infoCtrl">
......
</div>
```

then problem comes, the 'scope' of infoCtrl will exist forever unless I reload page; and my controller code like this

```
myApp.controller('infoCtrl',function($scope,$rootScope){
  $scope.$on('get data',function(e,args){
     console.log('get data',args);
     //make request
  }
}
```

as my code, while infoCtrl element be recreate, scope will be duplicated, and make multiple same request

right now I use a ugly fix to check $scope.$id and save it locally, check it before request, only enable the controller with newest id.

Is there other way to prevent scope be duplicate?

Comment: why mixing up jquery with angular, use `$http` instead. that would do run digest cycle for you..

Comment: I changed $.ajax block to 
$http.get(templateUrl)
 .success(function(result){
    el.html(result).show();
    $compile(el.contents())(scope);
})

but problem doesn't change